# .NET Core MVC - AJAX POST Request with prefix binding

Tags: javascript, c#, json, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I would like to post a request via AJAX to a Controller with a model prefix. I need a prefix as I have two forms on one page with similiar model properties ("asp-for" is generating similiar IDs and Names). I'm using .NET Core 3.1.

Request post works fine without a prefix. When I'm using a prefix like in the example below, passed model is null in Controller:

### Controller with prefix

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Save([Bind(Prefix="ShipmentAddress"), FromBody]ShipToAddressViewModel model)
    {
        // model is null
        ...
        return PartialView(ShipmentAdressFormView, model);
    }
```

### View with prefix

In my View I set the HTMLFieldPrefix as well:

```
@model ShipToAddressViewModel
@{
    ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = "ShipmentAddress";
}
...
$("body").on('submit','#formShipmentAddress', function (e) {

    // Getting the data (see passed JSON below)
    var formData = new FormData(<HTMLFormElement>document.getElementById('formShipmentAddress'));
    var object = {};
    formData.forEach(function (value, key) {
        object[key] = value;
    });
    var data = object;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: (data) => {
            success(data);
        }
    });
});
```

### Passed JSON payload with prefix

```
{"ShipmentAddress.ID":"3","ShipmentAddress.Name":"Eddard Stark","ShipmentAddress.Name2":"c/o Ned",..."}
```

### Model

```
public class ShipToAddressViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Name 2")]
    public string Name2 { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

## UPDATE

If I remove the prefix from keys of my objects, then it works, though more like a work around (Model binding starts by looking through the sources for the key ShipmentAddress.ID. If that isn't found, it looks for ID without a prefix.):

```
    // Getting the data (see passed JSON below)
    var formData = new FormData(<HTMLFormElement>document.getElementById('formShipmentAddress'));
    var object = {};
    formData.forEach(function (value, key) {
        object[key.replace("ShipmentAddress.","")] = value;
    });
    var data = object;
```

Comment: Eddard Stark :'(

Comment: I get the data by looping through the form data, which works even with your example when I replace the prefix with "nothing". The datatype has no influence, .NET can parse it anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Asp.Net Core, there are two ways to bind the model, `ModelBinding` and `JsonInputFormatter`. For sending request with json, it will use `JsonInputFormatter`. `Bind` will not work with `JsonInputFormatter`.

Here is a working demo like below:

1.View:

```
@{
    ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = "ShipmentAddress";
}

@model ShipToAddressViewModel
<form id="formShipmentAddress">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="ID" class="control-label"></label>
        <input class="form-control" asp-for="ID">
        <span asp-validation-for="ID" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
        <input class="form-control" asp-for="Name">
        <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Name2" class="control-label"></label>
        <input class="form-control" asp-for="Name2">
        <span asp-validation-for="Name2" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
@section Scripts
{
<script>
    $("body").on('submit', '#formShipmentAddress', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();            
        var id = parseInt($("#ShipmentAddress_ID").val());
        var name = $("#ShipmentAddress_Name").val();
        var name2 = $("#ShipmentAddress_Name2").val();
        var data = {
            ID: id,
            Name: name,
            Name2: name2
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/Save",
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: (data) => {
                success(data);
            }
            });
    });
</script>
}
```

2.Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Save([FromBody]ShipToAddressViewModel model)
{
    //do your stuff...
}
```

3.Result:
[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your elaborating and illustrative answer, but there is some confusion: In your example you pass following json: `{"ID":3,"Name":"Eddard Stark"..},` instead of `{"ShipmentAddress.ID":3,"Name":"ShipmentAddress.Eddard Stark"..},`. That's why it's working. .NET Core has a fallback: Model binding starts by looking through the sources for the key AddressShipoment.ID. If that isn't found, it looks for ID without a prefix. So I removed manually the prefix in JavaScript before sending it back, then it works. Though it's actually more a work around. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Yes,I know what you mean.I could not get json like yours with suffix by using your code.Could you share how do you get the data?Did you try to change `ShipToAddressViewModel model` to `ShipToAddressViewModel 
 ShipmentAddress` in your action?

Comment: I updated my question, where I explained how I get the data (look at "View with prefix" and "Update"). Using `ShipToAddressViewModel ShipmentAddress` didn't work either.

Comment: For Asp.Net Core, there are two ways to bind the model, `ModelBinding` and `JsonInputFormatter`. For sending request with json, it will use `JsonInputFormatter `. `Bind` will not work with `JsonInputFormatter`.

Comment: Ah ok, so [Bind Prefix] doesnt work at all with JSON Request. I will change the keys of my objects then to send my data in this format: {"ID":3,"Name":"Eddard Stark"..}

Comment: @rena, please add your last comment to the top of your current answer, it answers the question perfectly, putting it up there for people having the same issue would prove VERY helpful

Comment: Hi @jalsh.Ok,I did.